# visual studio express 2012 version control

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, visual-studio-express

I have been sent a working project from a coworker to start learning Visual Studio. The project is under version control, however I don't want to have access to final customer product. So when I try to open the solution file I first get a message that the project is under source control:

"Team Foundation Server Version Control
The solution you are opening is bound to source control on the following Team foundation Serer:
http://    . Would you like to contact this server to try to enable source control integration?"
[yes]  [no]  [help]

I press no, then I get an error:

"The solution appears to be under source control, but its binding information cannot be found. Because it is not possible to recover the missing information automatically, the projects whose bindings are missing will be treated as not under source control."
[ok]  [help]

I proceed and press ok, and another message pops up:

"projectname\projectname.tsproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?prd=12395&pver=11&sbp=ProjectTypeDeprecated&plcid=0x409&clcid=0x409&ar=MSDN&sar=ProjectCompatibility&o1=B1E792BE-AA5F-4E3C-8C82-674BF9C0715B"

My coworker tells me he sent the whole project, so I can't figure out why I cant get visual studio to open it. I am new to visual studio, but I have some programming experience.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is doubtful that version control has something to do with your problem. There are two possibilities I could think of:

1. Your coworker uses full version of VS2012 and you are now having problems due to the fact that Visual Studio Express comes in two main flavours - Web and Desktop. It is unable to load Web(or Desktop) project because it just does not have any tools to work with it. Ask your coworker whether they mix web and desktop in their solutions. If it is so you should either use full VS or be given a reduced set of projects.
2. Nearly the same - your coworker uses some very old or very new version of particular project type (something like ASP.NET MVC that(as I remember) has different project type for each version). Again ask your coworker if it is so. In this case you will just have to install the needed templates and SDKs.

P.S. I was unable to open your link - it opens microsoft.com/default(maybe due to some regional problems). Search by key words brought to me similar problem for VS2010 http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728847/could-not-open-vs2010-solution-with-mvc-project - may be it could help you more specifically.

Comment: Thank you very much, when he comes back I will ask him.